# Fetching JWT token each refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, pinia

What my code is doing currently is calling a function that calls an api that gives a new access token every time the page gets refreshed, or to be more specific i have a pinia store that has a function that adds the data to the store when called and this function is being called when the page refreshes.

I am doing this because I have a thing that says "logged in as x" on the navbar and to get that info I go check if the refresh token is valid and fetch the username at the same time.

I'm wondering if this is a bad idea and if I should do it some other way, like storing the username in localstorage/cache/cookies

(sorry for bad phrasing)

Comment: In general, one access token is enough and it can contain general info about the user as jwt token and you can simply use `jwt.verify` to get the user's info or [more](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken). But an access token can have an expiration if you set a short period like 10 minutes, you should send a refresh token to the client as a cookie, and after the access token expired with new access token can get with only a refresh token.

Comment: ok thank you that clears it up a little

Comment: @configtheworld I would really not advices to store user data in the JWT token, other than the highly necessary like the user id (in the sub claim), since this data is unencrypted. Just load the user data from the protected rest api on page load.

Comment: @Gabe Yes, I meant user id, user type, etc as general info.